# generate list of c++ methods called from an executable

Tags: c++, import, dumpbin, readelf

Is there a way to generate a list of C++ methods being called for an executable? I have a dynamic library and would like to see how many of the methods are being called from the executable. I can see that the C++ methods are being exported through dumpbin or readelf. However, when I run these tools on an executable that is calling the dynamic library, only the C methods and one C++ method is being listed. Is there something special with C++ imports?

Comment: Just about any decent (or even crappy) profiler should be able to tell you. If you want a list of what's potentially called, the import table of the executable should tell you (at least right now, it sounds like you're looking at exports, not imports).

Comment: Looks like you're after a code coverage test or some sort of profiling. Tools exist that do that.

Comment: Yes I am trying to do a code coverage test of a class library. At this point, I am not so interested of the code coverage at run time so I wanted to see if I could do something quick with dumpbin or readelf, but it doesn't seem like it is possible with these tools?

Answer (score 1):

You can build your library and program with profiling, then you can get a list of all functions called (and how much time is spent in each function).

You can also add manual trace logging, meaning you add a call that writes to the console at the start and end of each function.

The profiling is probably the simplest and easiest way to go. Look [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#index-g_t_0040command_007bgprof_007d-567) for the option needed when building, and e.g. [here](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.16/gprof/) for a manual of the program `gprof` needed for extracting the information.

Answer (score 0):

You could use profiling techniques, e.g. compile your entire program with the `-pg` flag passed to `gcc` (and at link time), then use `gprof`. (There is also `oprofile`).

You could use `ltrace` to understand the library calls done.

You might be interested by this [article about reverse engineering tools](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/reverse-engineering-tools/).